# passing auto incremented id through forms

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to do a simple login with a SQLServer database, and I'd like to know how I can pass the user_id once the confirmation works.

```
private void login_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='D:\Visual Studio\Test 3\Database\users.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        String sqlquery = "select username,password from user_creds where username='"+username.Text+"' and password='"+pass.Text+"'";

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adp.Fill(ds);

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

        if (dt.Rows.Count >=1)
        {
            home fl = new home();
            this.Hide();
            fl.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid login credentials.");
        }
```

Comment: You could make a static class that holds all login information

Comment: Read [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) first before you continue any sql programming.

Comment: I do know about SQL injection but this program will be offline for the most part.

Comment: You could pass the userid through the constructor of `home`